# How we get value from Controller to Plain html

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, model-view-controller, entity-framework-4

How I can get the value of `_m.Url` from controller to Plain HTML

```
EmailModel _m = new EmailModel();
if (Ads.Email != null)
{
    _m.toAddress.Add(Ads.Email);
    _m.Url = "http://www.bedspacefinders.com/PostBedAds/AllPostBeds/" + be.AdvertisementID;
    _m.Subject = "Welcome Your Ads is Live ";
    _m.Body= System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/EmailTemplate/EmailFormat.html"));
}
```

I want this value `_m.Url` to in this HTML `li`

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Can you try to elaborate more?

Comment: You should be able to go through the Razor binding syntax as http://www.asp.net/mvc to understand how to bind HTML items to data sources. I'd start there first, then come back with more specifics.

Comment: @PeterBons I have value in controller like _m.Url. So i want to this value into Plain HTML paragraph for showing this value is dynamically changed so i dont want use Razor view. I want this value in Plain HTML in Paragraph.